# I want to disable cut copy features in the clipboard group of Home tab in the excel programmatically using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have a requirement from a client that they want to disable the copy & Cut buttons from the Clipboard group in Home tab in Excel ribbon.

Look at the screenshot mentioned below which I need to disable for them. Please let me know if this is possible or not

[Screen Shot of excel ribbon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/omIqD.png)

I wanted to disable which is rounded up in the image.

I have tried below code but no luck still the copy button is not disabled.

```
Application.OnKey "^c", "" ' Disable Ctrl+C (Copy)
Application.OnKey "^v", "" ' Disable Ctrl+V (Paste)
Application.OnKey "^x", "" ' Disable Ctrl+X (Cut)
Application.OnKey "+{DEL}", "" ' Disable Shift+Delete (Cut)
Application.OnKey "^{INSERT}", "" ' Disable Ctrl+Insert (Copy)
Application.OnKey "+{INSERT}", "" ' Disable Shift+Insert (Paste)

Application.CutCopyMode = False
Application.OnKey "^c", ""
Application.CellDragAndDrop = False
```

Comment: What is the idea behind that? If someone would try to steal my Copy+Paste from Office, I would be **very** angry. And immediately start to write some macros to enable it again.

Comment: I believe your best option is to have a macro that runs every second that clears the copy memory with `Application.CutCopyMode = False`. But that is not a great idea. What is the issue with cut and copy? Perhaps there is some way that you can still use them but not in some specific way that the client doesn't like

Comment: What is the reason behind this? Without understanding what this is supposed to prevent it's pretty difficult to come up with a good solution - The requirement "Disable the cut and copy buttons" really sounds like someone with limited technical knowledge trying to present you with a solution rather than a requirement. Because disabling the buttons does little to prevent people from copy and pasting. To come up with a solution it would be better to know why?/what something is supposed to achieve instead of how to implement it (because if they had the knowledge to implement they'd not need you.

Comment: What about SavingAs .xlsx,.csv ... and opening that - removing the copy/cut protection (for the data) - What about exporting the workbook. What about Power Query or Mail Merge. There are sooooo many ways to get the data out of the excel Workbook that are not even Copy/Cut and Paste.  - If the requirement is because they want to prevent data from being copied to somewhere else, then excel is probably not the right fit. If copy/cut should be disabled for some other reason they should probably tell you that reason so you can think of a solution to that specific problem